# How to add animation transition to NavigationUI in android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

i'm using NavigationUI to tie destinations to menu items, but how to override the default animation transition?

Based on the doc https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer, i cant find any method that can add the animation transition.

Comment: check this : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NavigationUI does not offer that API. However, there's absolutely no requirement to use `NavigationUI` - it is only optional helper methods.

Therefore you can copy / build a simplified version of [what it actually does](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/navigation/ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.java#74):

```
NavOptions navOptions = new NavOptions.Builder()
    .setLaunchSingleTop(true)  // Used to prevent multiple copies of the same destination
    .setEnterAnim(R.anim.your_enter_anim)
    .setExitAnim(R.anim.your_exit_anim)
    .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.your_pop_enter_anim)
    .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.your_pop_exit_anim);
    .build();

// Assuming you have a MenuItem named item
navController.navigate(item.getItemId(), null, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but recently i encountered same problem .
Here is the ideal solution to override default transition animations in **NavigationUI**

[Click Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/537#issuecomment-455187020)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, by creating default navigation animation resources in the 'animator' resource directory. I have created these four animator resource files-

- res/animator/nav_default_enter_anim.xml
- res/animator/nav_default_exit_anim.xml
- res/animator/nav_default_pop_enter_anim.xml
- res/animator/nav_default_pop_exit_anim.xml

The rests are the same, just follow the Google's official guide to set up bottom navigation bar.

```js
bottomNavBar = binding.bottomNavBar
        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fNavHost) as NavHostFragment

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavBar, navHostFragment.navController)
```