# Reload navigation fragment with bundle arguments and animation, called from within itself

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a **navigation fragment** which accepts data to display from bundle arguments. After user action, this fragment is 3 level deeper from the nav host activity. There is option to go next or previous (**multiple times**) which should reload the same fragment, but with newer data. For next/prev loading, if I create bundle and call `Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate`, on an action pointing to itself, it just keeps on adding same fragment to the stack.

inside `<navigation>` tag of file `app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"` along with other fragments

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/questionFragment"
        android:name="activities.qacenter.QuestionFragment"
        android:label="fragment_question_center"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_question">
        <argument
            android:name="questionObj"
            app:argType="model.Question" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_questionFragment_self"
            app:destination="@id/questionFragment" />
    </fragment>
```

Click listener for forward button inside `override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`

```
forward.setOnClickListener {
        if (thisQ?.questionNo != null) {
            val curQNo = thisQ?.questionNo!!
            val curLevelNo = thisQ?.qOfLevel!!
            val totalQCount = thisQ?.totalQCount!!
            if (curQNo < totalQCount) {
                val bundle = Bundle()
                val etActivity = context as eTLanding
                val wholeQSet =  etActivity.getSelectionSet()!!
                var questionSet = wholeQSet[curLevelNo-1].questions!!
                var nextQuestion = questionSet[curQNo]
                bundle.putSerializable("questionObj", nextQuestion)
                Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.action_questionFragment_self, bundle)
            } else {
                forward.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I **replace** the currently displayed fragment with popToLeft/Right **animation** for previous and next button clicks?

I am using `onViewCreated` to bind data to view elements and attach button listeners

Comment: Will I have to do this for animation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51856988/1029110

Comment: Why do people use `onActivityCreated`? Why is that method so popular?

Comment: Corrected to onViewCreated in code & question. Still same issue

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that's because there is an app on Google codelabs that does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856988/navigation-component-set-transition-animation-programmatically) with minor adjustments like adding more arguments as per my need

```
internal fun navigateWithAnimation(actionId: Int, beginStackFrag: Int, anyView: View, isBackNav: Boolean, bundle: Bundle) {

        val navBuilder = NavOptions.Builder()

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(anyView)
        // val currNavigationNode = navController.graph.findNode(beginStackFrag)

        if (isBackNav) {
            navBuilder.setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_out_right)
        } else {
            navBuilder.setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_out_left)
        }
        navBuilder.setPopUpTo(beginStackFrag, false)

        navController.navigate(actionId, bundle, navBuilder.build())
    }
```

Alternative [How to add animation transition to NavigationUI in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699791/1029110)